# Preventing the pump from sucking air when the tank is empty

Tags: plumbing, water, water-pressure, irrigation

I have a pump connected to a water tank.
The city water fills the tank through a (mechanical) float valve (to prevent overfill).
And the pump's inlet is connected to both the tank's outlet, and also the city water pipe (through two check valves, so that the tank won't be over-filled through its outlet).

The problem is that, if the tank is empty, the pump will suck air through the tank (instead of just sucking water through the city water pipe).
The solution I thought of was to mount a [float valve](https://royal.ps/storage/products/September2021/OIiyDlmUiVQHY0oSA8Cm.jpg), albeit inverted, to the outlet of the tank, so that when the tank is empty, it would shut the outlet.

Would this solution work? would there be any problems with it?

Edit:
A Schematic of what I'm trying to setup:
[image]

The reason I want the city water pipe to be connected directly to the pump is because of low city water pressure which could fail to keep up with the rate at which the water is getting depleted from the tank, especially if the consumption is high (and the tank could go dry).

The problem is that I think if the tank goes dry, even with the city water pipe connected to the pump's inlet, it will suck air through the empty tank.

Comment: Wait, isn't the city water line under considerable pressure (like municipal water systems typically are)? If so, how come water is even pulled from the tank instead of city water just flowing freely through the pump? And why is the pump even connected to city water when the same water is also used to fill the tank?

Comment: It might help to include a diagram of your setup, as this strikes me as a reasonably uncommon setup for those of us in the US (where many of your answerers are).

Comment: Why not just always pump from the tank and put a float switch in the tank to prevent pumping when it's dry? If city water is available then it'll fill the tank as you pump from it.

Comment: Do you need the city water to go through the pump? Would the city water pressure be enough?

Comment: Thank you everyone; I edited the question.

Comment: If use is > supply from utilities then tank will empty. If it empties, it will suck air - no choice. Only way is to reduce use, so water supply can catch up. Pump shutoff on empty will do this, allowing tank to fill. If u really want more storage, add more and larger tanks.

Comment: You could rig something so when pump shuts off, it opens alternate by-pass-the-tank water line which just flows. When u stop using water, it starts to fill tank again for next time

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/12783/increasing-water-pressure-with-pump - they should be pressure tank*s* (*plural*. checkout those valves in the link that shut off under 20psi) a 20m shower is 50 gallons. So my hour long ones use +150. - How many gallons of storage do you have (which isn't enough, whatever it is). Does the schematic look ok? IDK, prob. *Will it do what you want?* Prob not. Otherwise this would be a dupe of *how to increase city water flow*. Which afaik *you don't* w/o an extremely elaborate setup and *a whole lot* of storage.

Comment: Back flow prevention? And spinning the pump *the whole time* with city water... ;\

Comment: Irrigation? You need to zone it for *that*. - Generally for *this* you would put a booster pump on the city line but those prob don't really work either. https://www.popularmechanics.com/home/a34437916/how-to-increase-your-water-pressure/

Comment: IDK schematics (and prob still can't help, even if you); show me the piping scheme with all its pumps, valves, check valves, and pressure tanks. And the GPM you get during 'low flow'; and the GPM we're trying to achieve. Then we might know how long it will do what you want (or not) with however much storage you have or would need.

Comment: Booster pump wyed off the main line asap, into a tank with an air bladder, wyed back into the main line after a check valve, where somehow the booster pump is shut off when you call for water (otherwise it just steals incoming pressure). You'd need like 20 tanks.... and another check valve on the main line just after the first wye, otherwise it goes in circles. (all of which sounds like non-sense, because it is)

Comment: Q: Would you prefer to have most of your pumped water direct from the city supply, and only supplemented by the tank when city supply is slow?

Answer (score 2):

Shutting the outlet will not protect the pump.

Fit a float switch to turn the pump off when the level is too low.

Comment: But I want the pump to keep running (and getting fed directly from the city water pipe ...)

Comment: @MicrosoftLinuxTM then connect the pump to the city pipe.